# In owl carousel - 1, can we use the same pagination for 2 different carousel sliders?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

```
            $(".row2-sliderLT").owlCarousel({
                slideSpeed: 600,
                paginationSpeed: 600,
                singleItem: true,
                autoHeight: true
            });

            $(".row2-sliderRT").owlCarousel({
                slideSpeed: 600,
                paginationSpeed: 600,
                singleItem: true,
                autoHeight: true
            });
```

this will create 2 owl-carousel sliders with 2 paginations of their own, now can we some how use the pagination created by the 1st slider for both sldiers??

Comment: amm...actually i dont knw how...could u give me some hint how i can use the same pagination for both sliders

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have there.

Comment: It's in the docs for Owl Carousel 1 and Owl 2.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and I've made it using owl2 evens:

**Demo: [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jZxmoz)**

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="ul1" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>n..</li>
</ul>

<ul id="ul2" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>n..</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

**JS (jQuery):**

```
$('#ul1').owlCarousel({
  items: 1,
}).on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
  console.log('ul2.trigger.to ' + e.item.index);
  $('#ul2').trigger('to.owl.carousel', e.item.index);
});


$('#ul2').owlCarousel({
  items: 3,
  dots: false,
}).on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
  console.log('ul1.trigger.to ' + e.item.index);
  $('#ul1').trigger('to.owl.carousel', e.item.index);
});
```